# how to create graph using networkx from text file?

Tags: python-2.7, networkx

I have a text file like this:

```
node1  node2  weight
1      2      3
1      4      4
3      6      1
3      7      5
....
....
```

I want to create a directed graph using networkx then count the degree and weight for each node.

```
import networkx as net
import urllib
import csv
g = net.Graph()
f1 = csv.reader(open("graphdata.txt","rb"))
for x,y,z in f1: 
    g.add_nodes_from(x,y,z)
```

It gives an error. Can anybody help me as to how build graph the compute the weight and degree for each node?

Comment: Can you please describe the error it is throwing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing you have to do is to comment any descriptive data in your file. By default, Networkx considers any line starting with # as a comment.

```
# node1 node2 weight
1 2 3
```

...

```
import networkx as net
FielName="GraphData.txt"
Graphtype=net.DiGraph()   # use net.Graph() for undirected graph

# How to read from a file. Note: if your egde weights are int, 
# change float to int.
G = net.read_edgelist(
    FielName, 
    create_using=Graphtype,
    nodetype=int,
    data=(('weight',float),)
)

# Find the total number of degree, in_degree and out_degree for each node
for x in G.nodes():
    print(
        "Node: ", x, " has total #degree: ",G.degree(x),
        " , In_degree: ", G.out_degree(x),
        " and out_degree: ", G.in_degree(x)
    )

# Find the weight for each node
for u,v in G.edges():
      print ("Weight of Edge ("+str(u)+","+str(v)+")", G.get_edge_data(u,v))
```

I recommend you to read the [Reading and writing graphs in Networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/index.html) and have a look to [read_edgelist](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/edgelist.html)