# Create Networkx Graph from CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, attributeerror

I am trying to build a NetworkX social network graph from a [CSV file](https://github.com/MelissaLaurino/DolphinSocialNetwork_Laurino/blob/master/test.csv). I am using Networkx 2.1 and Python 3

I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43561944/how-to-create-graph-using-networkx-from-text-file) with no luck because I keep receiving the error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

My goal is to make the weights display thicker edges for the higher weights.

Here is my code so far:

```
import networkx as nx
import csv

Data  = open('testest.csv', "r", encoding='utf8')
read = csv.reader(Data)
Graphtype=nx.Graph()   # use net.Graph() for undirected graph

G = nx.read_edgelist(read, create_using=Graphtype, nodetype=int, data=(('weight',float),))

for x in G.nodes():
      print ("Node:", x, "has total #degree:",G.degree(x), " , In_degree: ", G.out_degree(x)," and out_degree: ", G.in_degree(x))   
for u,v in G.edges():
      print ("Weight of Edge ("+str(u)+","+str(v)+")", G.get_edge_data(u,v))

nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

Is there a more simplified way to approach this? The data is relatively simple.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: We cannot reproduce the error without a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Could you upload the `csv` file, or a part of it?

Comment: Thank you for the tip, added to Github. @ducminh I am new to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 14):

You are misusing the function `read_edgelist`. From the [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/edgelist.html), each line needs to be parsed a string, while `csv.reader` parses the lines in the input file into lists of strings (for example, `202,237,1 -> ['202', '237', '1']`). Therefore, `AttributeError` is raised because `read_edgelist` is trying to parse the lists provided by `csv.reader`, while they should be strings.

We can correctly parse the graph from the input file without using the `csv` module. However, we still need to deal with the first line (the headers) of the input file, which should not be parsed. There are two methods. The first method skip the first line using `next`:

```
Data = open('test.csv', "r")
next(Data, None)  # skip the first line in the input file
Graphtype = nx.Graph()

G = nx.parse_edgelist(Data, delimiter=',', create_using=Graphtype,
                      nodetype=int, data=(('weight', float),))
```

The second method is a bit "hacky": since the first line starts with `target`, we mark the character `t` as the start of a comment in the input file.

```
Data = open('test.csv', "r")
Graphtype = nx.Graph()

G = nx.parse_edgelist(Data, comments='t', delimiter=',', create_using=Graphtype,
                      nodetype=int, data=(('weight', float),))
```

In both methods, we have to use `parse_edgelist` instead of `read_edgelist` because the input file uses `\r` for newlines. To use `read_edgelist`, the file needs to be opened in binary mode, whose lines are split iff [the newlines are either `\r\n` or `\n`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readline). Thus the input file with `\r` newlines cannot be split into lines, and thus cannot parsed correctly.

Also, since you want to find the in-degrees and out-degrees, the graph should be created using `DiGraph`, not `Graph`.

## Edit

The key point here is to skip the header in the input file. We can achieve this by first reading the input file into a `pandas.DataFrame`, then we convert it to a graph.

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
Graphtype = nx.Graph()
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, edge_attr='weight', create_using=Graphtype)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @ducminh!!! How would it change if I chose to only graph certain nodes from the data instead of all of the nodes? I am asking because of the specifications of the second method parsing an edge list (Which was the method I found to work the best!). (Example: If you only wanted to look at nodes 6, 240 and 282, along with the nodes they are connected to).

Comment: @Melissa I can think of two ways: either you filter the rows of the DataFrame, then create the graph from the filtered data, or you can create the full graph first, then take the subgraph. The first approach would be more efficient.