# Creating a networkx graph from a tab - delimited text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

So I've got a text file with the following data:

```
35467 17494 1197992662 
35467 4190  \N
35467 18822 1209937599 
37188 7741 1219156787 
37188 8561 1199853037
```

I'd like to create a networkx graph using just the first two columns as my nodes and the edge being whether the first two numbers are on the same row while ignoring the 3rd column completely.

Comment: what do you mean by 'whether the first two numbers are on the same row'? In this example, can you tell which are edges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to interpret your file as edge list, while ignoring all values behind the first two `columns`, following should work:

```
import networkx as nx
import csv

g = nx.Graph()
csvfile = csv.reader(open("test.csv", "r"), delimiter="\t")
for line in csvfile:
    x, y = line[:2]
    g.add_edge(x, y)

print(g.nodes())
# ['35467', '17494', '4190', '18822', '37188', '7741', '8561']
print(g.edges())
# [('35467', '17494'), ('35467', '4190'), ('35467', '18822'), ('37188', '7741'), ('37188', '8561')]
```

Probably the following question may be worth a look, if it's not exactly what you want:

- [Create Networkx Graph from CSV file in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49683445/create-networkx-graph-from-csv-file-in-python-3)
- [how to create graph using networkx from text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43561944/how-to-create-graph-using-networkx-from-text-file)
- [unable to load a simple csv in networkx in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22768224/unable-to-load-a-simple-csv-in-networkx-in-python)